# Login form - Apps Script and google-sheets

Tags: forms, web-applications

I am trying to make a login form using google app script. The steps I need are as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1BDE.jpg)

My trying is:
here is my gs code:
i am new please help me

```
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyGvCiggfwsHQfcqs5HBFZj2LS0idotzLBGMQUzAoSIn3ucZuPNLR7t4sYigfDyIOY5/exec";
function doGet(e){
  var user = e.parameter.name;
  var password = e.parameter.pass;
  var users = ["admin","123","user","456","guest","789"];
  var message ='';
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  for (var i =0;i<users.length;i++){
    if(users[i][0]== user && users[i][1]== password){
      message='';
      const show = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("show");
      return show.evaluate();
      
    }else{
      message='fail to login try again!'
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("login");
      return template.evaluate();
    }
  }
      
}
```

my login.html

this is my html for the webapp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>EPSP-TGGT</title>
  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary mb-2 text-center text-white">
            Admin
          </div>
          <form id="myForm"> 
            <h4> "<?!= message ?>"</h4>           
            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap  mb-2">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap mb-2">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrappingg">@</span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="sample()" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Login</button>            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JS-Code To get user & pass and put them as Paramaters in the script-url -->
  <script>
    function sample() {
      const url = "<?!= url ?>";
          const [name, pass] = ["name", "pass"].map((e) => document.getElementById(e).value);
          window.open(`${url}?name=${name}&pass=${pass}`, "_top");
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

The web app only can access by valid users that have permission to access the web app. After validation of a user, a new page open where user can operate will appear

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from your question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue? And also, can you provide the settings of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:` of your Web Apps? And, can you provide `show`?

Comment: Execute as:me / Who has access to the app: everyone

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. From `Execute as:me / Who has access to the app: everyone`, I understood only the setting of your Web Apps. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.